# load content of blog post in html file into template then into index file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html file which has blog post content and a template for a div in another html file.

I just want take blog post content and paste it in blog post template body and load them to index html file.

**Content html file**

```
 <h1>Computer Science In Today</h1>
 <p>  body </p>
```

**Post Template**

```
 <div class="blog-post-type-1">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="blog-post-content">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <img src="bg.png"/>
        <img src="fgg.png"/>
        <img src="background.png"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**index.html file**

```
  <body>
     <div class="wraper">


     <div class="all-blog-post">

     </div>
     </div>
  </body>
```

I want to add blog post inside of all-blog-post part. I know `document.getElementById('all-blog-post').innerHTML`, but I donot know how to take content and put it into template then all of them should be in all-blog-post part. How can I do that or is it possible to do it? Actually, is it meaningful to do so? If no, what should I do?

Comment: do you have any kind of trigger to do this? or just on load of index.html?

Comment: @Bradley there is no and trigger. When index page loaded to the client, I just want to load last three blog posts, in html file format, from content folder into index blog post div area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would reverse the steps that your taking to do this. First, you'll need a wrapper above the content at the top of content.html so it would look like this:

```
<div class='content-class'>
 <h1>Computer Science In Today</h1>
 <p>  body </p>
</div>
```

After that youll want to use the jquery load function to insert the html into your index.html:

```
    $(document).ready(function){ 
        $('.all-blog-post').load('place-path-here/content.html');
     }
```

Once thats done, youll want to place that blog data into the right wrapper so the whole jquery call would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function){ 
     $('.all-blog-post').load('place-path-here/content.html');
}

 $(document).on('load', '.blog-post-content', function(){
     var blog-post-content = $('.content-class').html();
     $(this).append(blog-post-content);
 });
```

Something like this should hopefully work, minus some possible syntax errors.

Comment: CAn you upvote question if you find interesting in order to overcome the limit? I have tried upvote you but it says I need at least 15. It is so restrictive.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as correct, but my upvote is not going to get you to 15.